# How was this particular equality manipulated?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

In Discrete Mathematics with Applications by Epps (5th Ed), on page 775 Example 11.2.4
[image]

My question relates to the bottom part of the above picture (the $(* *)$ step).

**Question:** I don't understand how $\frac{10}{n^{2}}+\frac{16}{n^{3}} \leq n$ was obtained from either multiplying or dividing by $2n^3$. Dividing $\frac{1}{2} n^{4}$ by $2n^3$ for example is $\frac{1}{4} n$ and multiplying is $n^7$. What am i missing here?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $\frac{2}{n^3}$

Comment: @William thank you. Why do you think they wrote $2n^3$ though and not $\frac{2}{n^3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$5n+8\leqslant\frac12n^4,$$you have$$\frac{5n+8}{\frac12n^3}\leqslant\frac{\frac12n^4}{\frac12n^3},$$which is the same thing as asserting that$$\frac{10}{n^2}+\frac{16}{n^3}\leqslant n.$$

Comment: Thank you. I asked this same question in a comment above, but why did they give the explanation "because dividing or multiplying both sides of an inequality by $2 n^{3}$.."? I don't understand how $2n^3$ relates.

Comment: My guess is that it is a typo and that the author actually meant $\frac12n^3$.